# azure invalid username when migrating django database

Tags: python, django, azure, deployment, hosting

I followed this :
[Tutorial: Deploy a Django web app with PostgreSQL in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=bash%2Cclone)

I created the DB and the app till I get to :

**Run Django database migrations**

Open an SSH session in the browser by navigating to
https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host
run the "python manage.py migrate"

it gives me this error

```
FATAL:  Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry 
connection. The Username should 
be in <username@hostname> format.
(antenv) root@5f4958961a00:/home/site/wwwroot#
```

I don't know which "Username" I should change to username@hostname

thnx in advance

Comment: Can you add your DATABASES setting to the question (obfuscating any sensitive data)

Comment: @lain Shelvington , az postgres up --resource-group DjangoPostgres-tutorial-rg --location westus2 --sku-name B_Gen5_1 --server-name marketreviewpostgres --database-name pollsdb --admin-user wert --admin-password ************** --ssl-enforcement Enabled

Comment: Your Django settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [create Postgres database in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=bash%2Cclone#create-postgres-database-in-azure) with commands:

```
az postgres up --resource-group DjangoPostgres-tutorial-rg --location westus2 --sku-name B_Gen5_1 --server-name <postgre-server-name> --database-name pollsdb --admin-user <admin-username> --admin-password <admin-password> --ssl-enforcement Enabled
```

When the command completes, it outputs a JSON object that contains different connection strings for the database along with the server URL, a generated user name (such as "joyfulKoala@msdocs-djangodb-12345"), and a GUID password.

For example,

```
...
  "host": "postgres-server-name.postgres.database.azure.com",
  "password": "somePassword",
  "username": "wert@postgres-server-name"
}
```

You could copy the user name and password like above format to [configure environment variables to connect the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-python-postgresql-app?tabs=powershell%2Cclone#configure-environment-variables-to-connect-the-database).

It worked on my side.
[image]